# Add local image as custom marker in google static maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-static-api

Can I set a local image in my local folder as a custom marker in googles static map API. i have seen examples fro setting markers images located in web. but here i want to use my own custom image. if i use an image from a url can i set the marker size?

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't use a local image directly out of your local folder.

You need to upload the image somewhere (in a web server) to make it accessible over HTTP. This is because Google servers need to download it, to then embed it into the map.

You should be able to use local images in the JavaScript API though, as they image will just go into some `img.src` and **your** browser should be able to display it. Not anybody else's browser though!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can: https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/custom-markers

```
var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  icon: iconBase + 'schools_maps.png'
});
```

[edit]

For static maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#CustomIcons

e.g.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=480x480&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_icon&chld=cafe%7C996600
```

> Note: The Google Static Maps API does not support custom icon URLs
>   that use HTTPS; the default icon will be displayed.

Comment: i think the question points to local image i.e in the project directory and thats not what your answer says